# Joomla 3.x insert query attempts don't work as desired

Tags: joomla-3.x, sql

Needing a little help to point me to the issue. I am building a component and need to insert a row into the Joomla DB.

This line works, but I have to create the table name myself and I'd rather use the built-in Joomla functions.

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$dbprefix = $config->get('dbprefix');
$db_arr = array($dbprefix,'conquest_ctg_players');
$table_name = implode("",$db_arr);  

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, ordering, state, checked_out, checked_out_time, created_by, modified_by, player_name, player_uuid, player_bann, player_level, player_xp, player_gold, resource_food, resource_supplys, resource_population, quest_energy, troops_basic, troops_advanced, jid)
          VALUES ('null', 1, '1', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '$userId', '$userId','$nUser', '$myuuid', '0', '1', '0', '50', '50', '50', '100', '100', '100', '0', '$userId')";
```

but this one errors out:

```
$sql
->insert($db->quoteName('#__conquest_ctg_players'))
->columns($db->quoteName('id', 'ordering', 'state', 'checked_out', 'checked_out_time', 'created_by', 'modified_by', 'player_name', 'player_uuid', 'player_bann', 'player_level', 'player_xp', 'player_gold', 'resource_food', 'resource_supplys', 'resource_population', 'quest_energy', 'troops_basic', 'troops_advanced', 'jid'))
->values(null, 1, 1, 0, $db->quote('0000-00-00 00:00:00'), $userId, $userId,$nUser, $myuuid,0, 1, 0, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 0, $userId);
```

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `ordering`) VALUES ()' at line 2

This one will create a new table entry but does not have any values.

```
$sql
->insert($db->quoteName('#__conquest_ctg_players'))
->columns(id, ordering, state, checked_out, checked_out_time, created_by, modified_by, player_name, player_uuid, player_bann, player_level, player_xp, player_gold, resource_food, resource_supplys, resource_population, quest_energy, troops_basic, troops_advanced, jid)
->values('null', '1', '1', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '$userId', '$userId','$nUser', '$myuuid', '0', '1', '0', '50', '50', '50', '100', '100', '100', '0', '$userId');
```

If anyone can tell me why they think it is adding a row, but not inputting info, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Christopher, we don't label pages as `[SOLVED]` in the title here.  Please do not edit your pages in this manner.  Awarding the green tick to the most helpful, resolving answer is the way to signify the resolution of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `#_` will spare you having to use a literal prefix value.  I recommend that you use this consistently throughout your project.
2. Your first attempt to use Joomla's query building syntax broke because [$db->quoteName()](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_quoteName) accepts a maximum of two parameters.  You have provided ...many.

   ```
   $db->quoteName('id', 'ordering', 'state', ...)
   ```

   Using an array as the first/only parameter would have saved you.

   ```
   $db->quoteName(['id', 'ordering', 'state', ...])
   ```
3. When inserting a new row that will generate a new auto-incremented value and you are naming columns, you may simply omit that column and its `null` value.  Alternatively, if you are filling EVERY column with a value, then you can omit the column names entirely.
4. As for the column and value methods:

   - [`columns()` expects a column or an array of columns.](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_columns)
   - [`values()` expects a string](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_values).
5. See https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Using_an_Object for an example of object syntax.  You may find it easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste time but i figured it out.

This way worked

```
$columns = array('id', 'ordering', 'state', 'checked_out', 'checked_out_time', 'created_by', 'modified_by', 'player_name', 'player_uuid', 'player_bann', 'player_level', 'player_xp', 'player_gold', 'resource_food', 'resource_supplys', 'resource_population', 'quest_energy', 'troops_basic', 'troops_advanced', 'jid');
$values = array(0, 1, 1, 0, $db->quote('0000-00-00 00:00:00'), $userId, $userId,$db->quote($nUser), $db->quote($myuuid), 0, 1, 0, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 0, $userId);
$sql
->insert($db->quoteName('#__conquest_ctg_players'))
->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
->values(implode(',', $values));
```